# Permutations in "PERSNICKETINESS" with Constraints on Letter Placement

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I'm tackling a combinatorial challenge with the word "PERSNICKETINESS". The task is to determine the number of permutations where the second "S" appears after the last vowel, considering letter frequencies of E (3x), S (3x), N (2x), I (2x), and each of P, R, C, K, T appearing once.

I've developed two methods to approach the problem but arrived at two different expressions for the solution. I'm seeking insights on which method (if either) is correct.

**Approach 1:**

1. **Vowels and the second S placement:** Considering a block of 6 characters (3 Es, 2 Is, and the second S), I calculated the ways to place this block in the 15 available positions as $$\binom{15}{6}$$.
2. **Internal arrangement of the block:** For the internal arrangement of this block, ensuring the second S follows all vowels, I used $$\frac{6!}{3!2!}$$ to account for repetitions.
3. **Remaining letters arrangement:** With 9 positions left, the arrangement of the remaining letters (including repetitions of S and N) is calculated by $$\frac{9!}{2!2!}$$.

**Expression 1:** Combining these steps, the expression for the total arrangements is derived from multiplying the outcomes of each step.

**Approach 2:**

1. **Treating the sequence as a block:** Here, I considered the vowels and the second "S" as a single block (6 elements total), effectively reducing the problem to arranging this block with the other letters.
2. **Calculating total permutations:** This approach calculates the total permutations by treating the block as a single entity, then multiplying by the internal permutations of the block (accounting for E and I repetitions).

**Expression 2:** The final expression for this method combines the permutations of treating the block as a single entity with the internal arrangements of the block.

Both approaches aim to ensure the second "S" follows the last vowel, but they lead to different final expressions and numerical outcomes. I would appreciate any clarification on the correct approach or any errors in my reasoning.

Comment: Second S appears fight after the last vowel or somewhere after the last vowel?

Comment: just appear after it in the arrangement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you first approach you don’t actually ensure that this S which goes after vowels is the *second* S. Also, why are you considering $6!\over 3!2!$. The letter S goes last, it doesn’t participate in permutations of the six letters.

Instead, you should consider all the vowels and the letters S. There are $15\choose 8$ ways to choose placements for them. Two letters S go last. The rest $6$ letters are placed in $6!\over 3!2!$ ways. After that, you place all the other letters in $7!/2!$ ways.

So the answer is $${15\choose 8}\times {6!\over 3!2!} \times {7!\over 2!}=972972000.$$

---

Here is a slightly different approach. There are $\frac{15!}{3!3!2!2!}$ overall permutations. What part of it suitable? Due to earlier reasoning it’s ${6!/(3!2!) \over 8!/(3!3!2!)}=\frac3{ 28}$. The answer is the same: $$\frac{15!}{3!3!2!2!} \times \frac 3{ 28}=972972000.$$

Comment: I'm confused, where did $8 ! /(3 ! 3 ! 2 !)$ in the second approach come from?

Comment: @neo $8!/(3!3!2!)$ is the number of ways to arrange $8$ letters: $3$ S, $3$ E, $2$ I. $6!/(3!2!)$ is the number of ways to arrange these same $8$ letters in a such a way that two S go last: we don’t actually arrange those two letters S. $6$ letters left of which $3$ E and $2$ I repeat.

Comment: Yeah I figured, thank you so much :)